# Safari gone from iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

My Safari app is missing from my iPhone. How do I get it back with all my bookmarks and history?

Comment: When you swipe down to Search for it, does it show up?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you've hidden or deleted it (I don't know for sure which it is for pre-installed apps).

Go to the App Store and search for Safari. You'll be able to "download" it back.

If the app has been deleted, in order to restore your data it depends on if you synchronized Safari bookmarks/history with iCloud.

**EDIT** : apparently the native apps are simply *hidden*.